# angular 2 routing: how to force an app to stay on current page and open a dialog

Tags: angular, routes

I am using angular 2.4.10. By clicking on a side menu item I navigate my site using a router:

```
import { ModuleWithProviders } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule } from '@angular/router';

... 
import { PartsComponent } from './parts/parts.component';
...

export const brambleRouting: ModuleWithProviders = 
RouterModule.forChild([
{
    path: '',
    component: BrambleRoot,
    canActivate: [AuthGuard],
    children: [
        ...
        {path: 'parts', component: PartsComponent},
        ...
        {path: 'model-builder', component: ModelBuilderComponent}
    ]
}
]);
```

As you can see I can navigate to the Parts component using the path and the associated PartsComponent.

Now the code to navigate to the ModelBuilderComponent is not want I want. The ModelBuilderComponent has an HTML file containing a modal popup. How do I define the route for the model builder so that my app stays on the current page and call the open-dialogue() function in the ModelBuilderComponent? Thank you for your help, Dino.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if the following is the right way to fix my problem but it works. In the end, I have added the templateUrl to the side-menu templateUrl:

```
<model-builder></model-builder>
```

now in the side-menu.component.ts I can run the openDialog() function and display the modal on top of the current page without being redirect to the model-builder page. Please feel free to comment and suggest better solutions.

Answer (score 0):

you can do that using common service between partsComponent and ModelBuilderComponent. make one observable variable in service and subscribe it in ModelBuilderComponent component so every time any other component changes that variable the subscribe method gets called in ModelBuilderComponent. so you can do what ever you want to do with it..

Answer (score 0):

you can try passing navigation extra option replaceUrl to false and skipLocationChange to true

```
this.router.navigate(['/model-builder], { replaceUrl: false, skipLocationChange: true });
```

Comment: This stops the page from being recorded in the browser history but the link still navigates to the model-builder page.